# Matching rows from a table

Tags: python, pandas, scrapy

I'm scraping this wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shopping_malls_in_the_South_Florida_metropolitan_area

And getting the data from the table, like this:

```
Location = response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table/tr/td[2]/a/text()').extract()[0]

Name =  response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table/tr/td[1]/a/text()').extract()
```

Once I have it, the plan is to add those list to a data frame. The issue is the that at the end I get:

```
len(Name)
 40
```

and

```
 len(Location)
47
```

This is because at some rows in the location column there are several elements, like in the third column where it is: Coconut Grove, Miami
there I get to elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) and `df` is first `df` of `dfs`:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shopping_malls_in_the_South_Florida_metropolitan_area',
                   header=0 )[0]
print df

                                  Name                           Location
0                        Aventura Mall                           Aventura
1                    Bal Harbour Shops                        Bal Harbour
2                  Bayside Marketplace                     Downtown Miami
3                   Boynton Beach Mall                      Boynton Beach
4                            CityPlace                    West Palm Beach
5                             CocoWalk               Coconut Grove, Miami
6                         Coral Square                      Coral Springs
7                        Dadeland Mall                            Kendall
8                         Dolphin Mall                         Sweetwater
9              Downtown at the Gardens                 Palm Beach Gardens
10                           The Falls                            Kendall
11          Galeria International Mall                     Downtown Miami
12     The Galleria at Fort Lauderdale                    Fort Lauderdale
13                    The Gardens Mall                 Palm Beach Gardens
14          The Grand Doubletree Shops                     Downtown Miami
15                 Las Olas Riverfront                    Fort Lauderdale
16                      Las Olas Shops                    Fort Lauderdale
17                   Lincoln Road Mall                        Miami Beach
18           Loehmann's Fashion Island                           Aventura
19                Mall of the Americas                              Miami
20            The Mall at 163rd Street                  North Miami Beach
21        The Mall at Wellington Green                         Wellington
22            Miami International Mall                              Doral
23                 Miracle Marketplace                              Miami
24              Metrofare Shops & Cafe  Government Center, Downtown Miami
25                 Pembroke Lakes Mall                     Pembroke Pines
26                 Pompano Citi Centre                      Pompano Beach
27                      Sawgrass Mills                            Sunrise
28                   Seminole Paradise                          Hollywood
29          The Shops at Fontainebleau                        Miami Beach
30  The Shops at Mary Brickell Village                    Brickell, Miami
31          The Shops at Midtown Miami                      Midtown Miami
32       The Shops at Pembroke Gardens                     Pembroke Pines
33           The Shops at Sunset Place                        South Miami
34                      Southland Mall                         Cutler Bay
35           Town Center at Boca Raton                         Boca Raton
36      The Village at Gulfstream Park                   Hallandale Beach
37             Village of Merrick Park                       Coral Gables
38                   Westfield Broward                         Plantation
39                       Westland Mall                            Hialeah
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need the correct xpath:

```
rows = response.xpath('//table[@class="wikitable"]//tr[not(./th)]')
for row in rows:
    print ''.join(row.xpath('.//td[1]//text()').extract()), ' | ' , ''.join(row.xpath('.//td[2]//text()').extract())

Aventura Mall  |  Aventura
Bal Harbour Shops  |  Bal Harbour
Bayside Marketplace  |  Downtown Miami
Boynton Beach Mall  |  Boynton Beach
CityPlace  |  West Palm Beach
CocoWalk  |  Coconut Grove, Miami
Coral Square  |  Coral Springs
Dadeland Mall  |  Kendall
Dolphin Mall  |  Sweetwater
Downtown at the Gardens  |  Palm Beach Gardens
The Falls  |  Kendall
Galeria International Mall  |  Downtown Miami
The Galleria at Fort Lauderdale  |  Fort Lauderdale
The Gardens Mall  |  Palm Beach Gardens
The Grand Doubletree Shops  |  Downtown Miami
Las Olas Riverfront  |  Fort Lauderdale
Las Olas Shops  |  Fort Lauderdale
Lincoln Road Mall  |  Miami Beach
Loehmann's Fashion Island  |  Aventura
Mall of the Americas  |  Miami
The Mall at 163rd Street  |  North Miami Beach
The Mall at Wellington Green  |  Wellington
Miami International Mall  |  Doral
Miracle Marketplace  |  Miami
Metrofare Shops & Cafe  |  Government Center, Downtown Miami
Pembroke Lakes Mall  |  Pembroke Pines
Pompano Citi Centre  |  Pompano Beach
Sawgrass Mills  |  Sunrise
Seminole Paradise  |  Hollywood
The Shops at Fontainebleau  |  Miami Beach
The Shops at Mary Brickell Village  |  Brickell, Miami
The Shops at Midtown Miami  |  Midtown Miami
The Shops at Pembroke Gardens  |  Pembroke Pines
The Shops at Sunset Place  |  South Miami
Southland Mall  |  Cutler Bay
Town Center at Boca Raton  |  Boca Raton
The Village at Gulfstream Park  |  Hallandale Beach
Village of Merrick Park  |  Coral Gables
Westfield Broward  |  Plantation
Westland Mall  |  Hialeah
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is consider the two words as one, you can do a string replace over the entire word to replace the comma with an empty string:

```
location = [loc.replace(',', '') for loc in location]
```